# Exact meaning of "sense of well being"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I want to find the exact/literal/detailed meaning of the phrase "sense of well being". Not just "well being", but "sense of well being". (What exactly is meant by "sense"?)

Note: I understand what the phrase means. But how will I write/describe the meaning in English? (I need this for some literary work.)

Comment: It is also worth noting, that in many cases it is used as an abstract term; thus allowing bodies to make 'fluffy' claims whilst avoiding definition of those claims i.e. "Usage of our product, X, will provide users a great sense of well being".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Oxford Food & Fitness Dictionary][1]:

> A positive state of mind that enables
>   a person to function effectively
>   within society. Individuals who have
>   good mental health are well-adjusted
>   to society, are able to relate well to
>   others, and basically feel satisfied
>   with themselves and their role in
>   society.

[1]: Read more: http://www.answers.com/topic/mental-health#ixzz1A4IzNBZt

Comment: This is a good answer, I feel like this sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

"A sense" in this case means that the person gets a taste of what it is like to be well-off, be it either physically, mentally, financially, or something else.  In other words, the person  to whom the phrase is applied reaches a *realization* of what "being well" means given the context.

Compare that to other phrases that start with "A sense of" - for example, if I volunteer with locals to clean up my street, I might get "a sense of community" out of the experience; that is, I begin to understand what it feels like to work together with members of my neighbourhood.

Answer (score 0):

From a "Mental Health" p.o.v. I believe it stems from stability. If a person does not feel a good "sense of well being", they're blind to feel something is not right which may affect other aspects of their liveslives. Otherwise having a good sense of well being by adapting to their surroundings in a much easier way.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/well-being):

> **well-being:** The state of being comfortable, healthy, or happy: *an improvement in the patient's well-being*.

Personal opinion: 
There's no accurate interpretations; it all depends on the subject's personality, character and experience. *To define is to limit.* (Oscar Wilde)

Answer (score -1):

An active part that enable person to function well among individuals. People who have good mental are well focus and able to do well among others.

Comment: I knew what it was starting to seem like as a sense of well being